# WOW Alliance saying equitant to Horde's "For the Horde!"

Tags: warcraft

I played WOW for many years, (The Burning Crusade, Wrath of the Lich King, and briefly Cataclysm).

Initially as Alliance, But mostly as Horde.

One thing I remember is the "Rallying cry" many players use in Horde, was "For the Horde!"

I vaguely remember that Alliance had a similar "Rallying cry" but cant remember it.

[It might have been "For the Alliance!" But that did not seem like what I remembered.]

What was the traditional Alliance rallying cry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed "For the Alliance!"

In the Broken Shore Alliance cinematic we can see Varian Wrynn using it:

And in the Battle for Lordaeron cinematic Anduin Wyrnn uses it:

Comment: Having grown up on Warcraft 2, I can say the Elven Archer says "For the Alliance!" while there are no Horde units that say "For the Horde!" so it would seem For the Alliance is actually the original and it was the Horde that copied it.

Answer (score 4):

**For the Alliance** was one of their many rallying calls. But something that a lot of people forget is that the Alliance is actually an alliance consisting of several sub-actions and religions.

- The 7 human kingdoms each having their own cry (For Lordaeron, for Stormwind, etc etc)
- The 3 dwarven kingdoms (For Ironforge!, For The Dark Iron Clan!)
- The Druids who devoted themselves to safeguard nature.
- The Kaldorei elves who worship The moon/Elune (In the name of elune!)
- The Holy light worshipped by The Humans, Dwarves, gnomes and Draenei and Worgen(For the light!, In the name of the light, etc).
- The Worgen Refuges from Gilneas (Vengeance for Gilneas!)

So yea they had a lot of war-cries but For the Alliance was not an uncommon one and probably more used for mixed forces.

On a side note, The Horde was no different (For The Forsaken, For the Banshee Queen, For Quel'thalas and so on) seeing it also comprised several religions, ideologies and nations.  Their most well known one would be *Lok'Tar Ogar* meaning Victory or Death.

An nice example of the Alliance using multiple war cries would be [the Wrath Gate incident](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch4rc5W4dKY&ab_channel=WorldofWarcraft).

Comment: Great. Seeing it said in the videos, recalled to me seeing/hearing it in game so many years ago. Thanks!

Comment: For Khaz Modan!